# Catching exceptions from a loop

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm trying to write a Forth word which will drop all items on the stack. I'm using a pretty dumb method, by running an infinite loop with 'drop' and catching the error when 'drop' fails because the stack is empty.

My words are defined as such:

```
( Infinite drop loop)
: droploop begin drop true while drop repeat ;

( Experimental catch with a single drop)
: dropcatcher ['] drop catch drop ;

( Like dropcatcher, but with 'droploop' instead of 'drop')
: dropall  ['] droploop catch drop ;
```

When I run droploop, I get an error like I'd expect and after execution, the stack is empty.
When I run dropcatcher, it drops if the stack isn't empty, and if the stack is empty it reports nothing.
When I run dropall, I get all sorts of stuff leftover on the stack.

It looks like this:

> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 dropall .s <9> -1 3 -1 5 -1 7 -1 9 -1  ok

I'd expect that dropall would simply clear the stack without complaint because droploop and dropcatcher seem to work right by themselves, but alas, I don't understand why dropall isn't working.

Why does dropall seem to work differently than droploop and dropcatcher? Or, what I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `droploop` throws an error, it will probably call [`ABORT`](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.0670) or [`-1 THROW`](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans9.htm#9.6.1.2275), which by definition clears the data stack.  So it may well be that `droploop` doesn't drop the right number of stack items before the error is detected, but the system exception handler does it for you.

When I run `droploop` myself, it either crashes or hangs.  This would seem to confirm my theory that there is a severe stack underflow.

As for the state of the stack after `dropall`, my guess would be that gforth maybe doesn't detect the stack underflow at the right time, and what you're seeing is some semi-random garbage.  Hence this is what `droploop` leaves on the stack before calling `ABORT`.

*Side note: Your `droploop` drops two stack items every iteration, which may or may not be what you intended.  Also, use `again` for an endless loop instead of `true while`.  I.e. `: droploop   begin drop again;`*

Of course, a better way to clear the stack would be

```
: clear   depth 0 ?do drop loop ;
```

or

```
: clear   begin depth while drop repeat ;
```

or

```
: clear   sp0 sp! ;
```